# Windows 10 1809 - Region/language registry keys

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

I got two simple question for you guys today, hopefully you can help me since I haven't been able to find it myself for some reason.

For Windows 10 1809 what registry keys controls the following settings?:

- Settings > Time & Language > Region > "Country or region"
- Settings > Time & Language > Language > "Preferred language" order of languages

I've tested quite a bit with the following keys, but they do not seem to control any of these five settings:

> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Locale > "(Default)" key
>   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language > "Default" key
>   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language > "InstallLanguage"
>   key   HKCU\Control Panel\International\Geo > "Nation" key
>   HKCU\Control Panel\International > "Locale" key
>   HKCU\Control Panel\International > "LocaleName" key

Answer (score 6):

That is five settings.

`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language!Default` is set by Regional Control Panel, Administrative tab, Language for non-Unicode Programs.

`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language!(Default)` is set by Regional Control Panel, Administrative tab, Language for non-Unicode Programs. (There can be multiple values for this).

`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language!InstallLanguage` is set by Windows setup and used by the Windows upgrade process.

`HKCU\Control Panel\International!Locale and LocaleName` are set by Regional Control Panel, Formats, Format.

`HKCU\Control Panel\International\Geo!Nation` is set by Regional Control Panel, Location, Home Location.

---

Windows 10 1809:

Settings > Time & Language > Region > "Country or region"

Updates:

`HKCU\Control Panel\International\Geo!Name`
`HKCU\Control Panel\International\Geo!Nation`

Settings > Time & Language > Language > "Preferred language"

Does not update any one registry key/value.  Sample:

`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\CTF\SortOrder\Language\00000000`
`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\CTF\SortOrder\Language\00000001`
`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\CTF\SortOrder\Language\00000002`

`HKCU\Control Panel\International\User Profile\[langid]\CachedLanguageName`

`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\International\AcceptLanguage`

`HKCU\Keyboard Layout\Substitutes\[langid]`

`HKCU\Keyboard Layout\Preload\2`

So if you're trying to determine what registry settings, you may have your work cut out for you.

Comment: To stay consistent with the rest of the search paths I think `\AcceptLanguage` needs to be replaced with `!AcceptLanguage` because it's a named value, not a key. Similarly, `\2` needs to be replaced with `!2` for the same reason. This may have changed since Windows 10 version 1809, so I don't want to edit the answer. I'm using Windows 10 version 21H1 (build 19043.1110).

Answer (score 0):

To change the "Preferred Language" and keep it like this:

Settings => Time & Language => Language => Spelling, Typing & Keyboard Settings => Advanced Keyboard Settings

Easiest method: Press "Start" and write "Advanced Keyboard Settings"